# Upload video from s3 to youtube

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5.1, youtube-data-api

I want to upload a video from s3 to youtube. Now i am using service account and get access token but when I upload video to youtube server return error:

```
[Google_Service_Exception]              


{                                       
   "error": {                             
    "errors": [                           
     {                                    
      "domain": "youtube.header",         
      "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",  
      "message": "Unauthorized",          
      "locationType": "header",           
      "location": "Authorization"         
     }                                    
    ],                                    
    "code": 401,                          
    "message": "Unauthorized"             
   }                                      
  }
```

This is my code:

```
    $googleClient = new Google_Client();
    $googleClient->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

    $googleClient->setApplicationName('XXX');
    $googleClient->setClientId('XXX');
    $googleClient->setClientSecret('XXXX');
    $googleClient->addScope(\Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE);
    $googleClient->setAccessType('XXX');
    $googleClient->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
    $googleClient->setDeveloperKey('XXX');

    $stringAccessToken = $googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()['access_token'];


    $googleClient->setAccessToken($stringAccessToken);


    $youtube = new \Google_Service_YouTube($googleClient);
....
```

I don't know Can use service account to upload a video to youtube api V3?

Please help me . thank you so much.

Comment: Are you using the correct API key?.